Minio mc sync deletes target before syncing updates
I'm trying to use the MinIO mc mirror command to regularly sync from a bucket to a file system. I've read the documentation but there is no mention of atomically replacing files on a new sync:
https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-mirror.html
Unfortunately, when I run this as a regular job, it deletes target files, then transfers each file again to a temp file, and then renames the temp file to the target file. I have no idea why it does this in this seemingly strange order, it would be much more sensible to transfer to a temp file and then rename that over the old version, specifically to avoid long periods with missing files. Large directory trees are usually out of sync, and large files can be missing for a long time.
I haven't found an option yet to avoid the files being deleted first. Is it possible?
